# Non-Typescripts imports failing when trying to incrementally convert to Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

So, we have decided to start converting our react app to Typescript. The plan is to do this gradually. From what I read online this shouldn't be an issue but, I have come across a problem when trying to convert over my "leaf-level" classes. So, here's my problem. My classes look like this:

*ModelClassA.ts*

```
export default class ModelClassA{ }
```

*ModelClassAFactory.js*

```
import {ProdTour}  from './ProdTour';
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "es6",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "allowJs": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "dom", 
      "es7"
    ]},
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

*webpack.js*

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'app': ["./scripts/EntryPoint.jsx", './Content/main.scss']
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", "ts"]
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/Scripts",
        filename: "[name].js"
    },
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    },
    module: {

        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: [{ loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true, minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' } }, 'sass-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }],
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: '../Content/main.css',
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
};
```

I get this error when running webpack:

> ERROR in ./scripts/Models/ModelClassAFactory.js Module not
>   found: Error: Can't resolve './ModelClassA' in
>   'C:\Source\scripts\Models\'
>   @ ./scripts/Models/ModelClassAFactory.js 8:16-37  @
>   ./scripts/Components/SomeComponent/SomeReducer.js  @
>   ./scripts/EntryPoint.jsx  @ multi ./scripts/EntryPoint.jsx
>   ./Content/main.scss

The error makes sense. The import on ModelClassAFactory file is looking for ModelClassA.js which has to be compiled from the .ts file. Any help would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** As per the code review by @TylerSebastian it was pointed out I was missing the "." on the "ts" in the extensions list `[".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", "ts"]`.

Comment: you're missing a `.` in your `extensions` webpack config `extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", "ts"]`. `ts` should be `.ts`

Comment: @TylerSebastian Well, that's embarrassing... Thanks for the code review!

Comment: I'll submit an answer. Accept it if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're missing a `.` in your extensions webpack config extensions: `[".js", ".jsx", ".tsx", "ts"]`. `ts` should be `.ts`